# Can i write a number in scientific notation using a variable? JAVA

Tags: java

Instead of writing the number : `1e4; // 10000.0` i want to do it as:

```
n = 4;
1en; // 10000.0
```

Its not possible to do that?

Comment: What?  No you cannot do that.

Comment: Isn't there any way around it?

Comment: You can use `Math.pow`

Comment: You can do `Math.pow(10, n)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use scientific notation in `double` literals. For example

```
double x = 3e4;
```

works just fine. This won't work if you replace `4` with a variable, so you can't write `3en`. The best you can do is:

```
int a = 3;
int n = 4;

double x = Double.parseDouble(a + "e" + n);
System.out.println(x);    // 30000.0

double y = a * Math.pow(10, n);
System.out.println(y);    // 30000.0
```